# Suppose $f$ is differentiable on $[a,b]$ and $\lim_{x\to a+}f'(x)=C$ then determine the right-hand derivative at $a$

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $f$ is differentiable on $[a,b]$ and $\lim_{x\to a+}f'(x)=C$ then determine the right-hand derivative at $a$

My attempt: Consider the interval $[a,a+h]$ then by the mean value theorem we have that $f'(c)=\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}$ for some $c\in [a,a+h].$ Now as $h\to 0$ we have that $f'(c)\to C$ and so the right hand derivative at $a$ is C itself. Is this correct?

Comment: You approach is standard and is key to proving an important property of derivatives namely that they don't have simple discontinuity.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $c$ is dependent on $h$, so for each $h$ we find a different $c_h$.
Now if we let $h\to 0$, then we see that $c_h$ converges to $a$ from the right (because $[a,a+h]\downarrow \{a\}$), so the right-hand derivative is $\lim_{h\downarrow 0}\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}=\lim_{c_h\downarrow a}f'( c_h)=C$.

So yes, it is correct, but you should make it a little more clear that the $c$ are dependent on $h$.